# How does Silverlight protect the AES keys it gets from PlayReady?

Tags: encryption, aes, decryption, silverlight

I'm doing some research about how Silverlight protects AES keys.

Here is the scenario: There is a smooth stream live encrypted channel service. When i log in to the service and tune the channel, silverlight makes a request to Playready Server to get the key for decrypt channel. I can see this traffic with Fiddler.
Here is an example of response:

> < AcquireLicenseResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
>   < AcquireLicenseResult>< Response> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages">< LicenseResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">< Version>1< /Version>< Licenses>< License>WE1SAAAAAAM/6X5HwA4LSn0j/310MwSKAAMAAQAAASQAAgAEAAAAKAACADYAAAAgAAAAOQAAABjYJ2Z4psK+RI+ICK4lWwGnAAMAAgAAADIAAAANAAAACgABAAEAMgAAAAwAAAANAAEANAAAAAoAlgAAADMAAAAKAAEAAwAJAAAApgABAAoAAACetP60ZllhUkqarGroOJD6fwABAAMAgOxOMdl6Sp6BZzA71EWt/XZSwwfYdViGXft7WPQeM5y77rKFTKLXvCbUna87O7IG2uw8/ArYY6Q/HxdewsYSTFHMni+VBM5FIjM9fhvfSX8/YDNyF2A7h1rxWtNSAikxKe/7rCQF3CLUzQsLXedyace89/S5O6sS5xgNhI/zNGdyAAEACwAAABwAAQAQqY9kZb/xLmZO3v1Pmp3/gg==< /License>< /Licenses>< /LicenseResponse>< /Response>< /AcquireLicenseResult>< /AcquireLicenseResponse>

For this tag the Microsoft documentation says it is a Base64 encoded string (but the string cannot be decoded with standard decoders).

I also try to write a Silverlight application that decodes this string with the Silverlight `decode` function, still cannot be decoded.

I want to find some detail, how does Silverlight protect these keys?

There are some projects about finding AES keys from memory dumps. In a master's thesis it is written that they found AES keys with the `aeskeyfind` program from a virtual machine memory dump. I tried the same but it failed.

Another project in GitHub says that it can find AES keys in a process. I tried it too (with the process id of the browser and plugin) but it failed too.

So is it impossible to find the key Silverlight got from PlayReady and if it is how Silverlight protects the AES keys?

Comment: Can you post an example of the base64 key you got? Why can't you decode it?

Comment: here is an example: WE1SAAAAAAM/6X5HwA4LSn0j/310MwSKAAMAAQAAASQAAgAEAAAAKAACADYAAAAgAAAAOQAAABjYJ2Z4psK+RI+ICK4lWwGnAAMAAgAAADIAAAANAAAACgABAAEAMgAAAAwAAAANAAEANAAAAAoAlgAAADMAAAAKAAEAAwAJAAAApgABAAoAAACetP60ZllhUkqarGroOJD6fwABAAMAgOxOMdl6Sp6BZzA71EWt/XZSwwfYdViGXft7WPQeM5y77rKFTKLXvCbUna87O7IG2uw8/ArYY6Q/HxdewsYSTFHMni+VBM5FIjM9fhvfSX8/YDNyF2A7h1rxWtNSAikxKe/7rCQF3CLUzQsLXedyace89/S5O6sS5xgNhI/zNGdyAAEACwAAABwAAQAQqY9kZb/xLmZO3v1Pmp3/gg==

Comment: That decodes from base64 just fine for me.

Comment: @mark what do you mean?

Comment: If I run it through the `base64` program from Linux "coreutils", I get 316 bytes of binary data.  Looking at the results in a hex editor, there are a couple bits that could be an encryption key, but nothing that really stands out.

Comment: Decode works fine with JavaScript `atob('WE1...')`. Binary strings starts wirh "XMR". [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838192(VS.95).aspx) mentions something about "PlayReady XMR" in Output Protection chapter. Have a look in this direction.